# Does astype edit original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a simple data frame df:

```
col1 | col2
 7   |  8
 12  |  14
```

When I check the data types of df by writing df.dtypes, int64 is the data type for both columns.

Now I go to change the data types for col1 by typing

```
df.astype({'col1': 'float64'}).dtypes
```

Which returns

```
col1    float64
col2      int64
dtype: object
```

Okay so far so good. So now when I double check to see if the data types have changed df...

```
df.dtypes
```

The output is

```
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object
```

See I thought astype would permanently change the data type of my original df. So I'm quite confused here. Why didn't the data types for df change?

Comment: There is a `copy` argument to determine this - see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: Hmm.. Lets check the docs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html. No it defaults to returning a copy

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) `astype` returns a copy, so you could do this:

```
df = df.astype({'col1': 'float64'})
```

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
df.col1 = df.col1.astype('float64')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the operation is not functioning `inplace` that's a reason why the argument `copy` is part of the function.

Furthermore, if you want the change to be permanent, you need to re-define your dataframe.

```
df = df.astype({'col1': 'float64'})
```

So that when you check for `df.dtypes`, `col1` will be float.

Answer (score 0):

to convert all numeric columns from float to int:
try this one out

```
df = df.astype({ x:'int32' for x in df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns })
```

this snippet for selecting all numberic columns

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
```